# Cancel uploads in onStatusChange

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fine-uploader

In our system we only allow uploads up to a specific number which can be done in multiple upload sessions. When the number of images in an upload session exceed this maximum number we are currently cancelling uploads in onStatusChange() instead of adjusting itemLimit:

```
 thumbnailuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
  element: document.getElementById('thumbnail-fine-uploader'),
  template: "qq-simple-thumbnails-template",
  request: {
    endpoint: 'uploader/uploader.php'
  },
  thumbnails: {
      placeholders: {
        waitingPath: "uploader/waiting-generic.png",
        notAvailablePath: "uploader/not_available-generic.png"
      }
  },
  validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp'],
      itemLimit: 6
  },
  callbacks: {
      onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
        //  console.log("submitting..." + id);
        },
        onStatusChange: function (id, oldStatus, newStatus) {
            // This will check to see if a file that has been cancelled
            // would equate to all uploads being 'completed'.

            if(parseInt(galleryImages) + id + 1 > MaxUploads && newStatus !== qq.status.CANCELLED){
                this.cancel(id);
                return;
            }

            if (newStatus === qq.status.CANCELLED) {
                check_done();
                return;
            }
        },
        onComplete: check_done,
        onUpload: StartUpload
    }
});
```

This seems to work well, but when switching on the debugger I get:

Error: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] 1 is not a valid file ID to upload!

in

```
now: function(id) {
var name = options.getName(id);

if (!controller.isValid(id)) {
   throw new qq.Error(id + " is not a valid file ID to upload!");
}
```

and a bunch of:

"[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Caught exception in 'onStatusChange' callback - element is undefined"

Can this be fixed or are these messages harmless?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you aren't using itemLimit?  This seems like a kludgey and user unfriendly alternative.

Comment: I tried itemLimit, but it didn't seem to have any affect when updating the itemLimit values after a first upload session. Also, it will show a default popup with text while we would prefer a customized solution. Also, I don't think it is user unfriendly, the upload will still work for those images within the max limit whereas itemLimit will cancel the full upload, the user will have to select images again... So if this is kludgey, what is the alternative keeping my comments in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the itemLimit"?  How are you "updating" this value?  Also, you can easily customize the popup text, and the popup container/method/UI.  See the styling docs for more info http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html.

Comment: I see you implemented SetItemLimit in 5.1.0, we use 5.0.3. I will check the latest version. Still a shame though no solution is provided for our approach since this.Cancel(id) is a simple API call provided by you. Or are we using it the wrong way?

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the itemLimit"? How are you "updating" this value?